# How to build frameworks for arm* architecture only, with Carthage?

Tags: ios, swift, build, app-store, carthage

I'm trying to build the project to be sent to the AppStore, and all dependencies are going to **arm * + i386 + x86_64**. I take Carthage. How to make the `assembly dependencies` only **arm ***?

Answer (score 0):

I had to read the [instructions](https://github.com/Carthage/Carthage#getting-started) carefully) Specifically, `carthage copy-frameworks`